# How to create a tweet using V2 API without Tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, python-3.5

I am trying the following code but it gives 401 error:

```
headers = {
                "Authorization": f"OAuth oauth_consumer_key={consumer_key},oauth_token={access_token},oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1"
            }
            # Create data payload for the tweet with attached media
            data = {
                "text": text,
                "media_ids": [media_id],
                "tweet_mode": "extended"
            }
            tweet_response = requests.post(tweet_post_url, headers=headers, data=data)
            print(tweet_response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired result by following the sample code provided below:

```py
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
import os
import json

# In your terminal please set your environment variables by running the following lines of code.
# export 'CONSUMER_KEY'='<your_consumer_key>'
# export 'CONSUMER_SECRET'='<your_consumer_secret>'

consumer_key = os.environ.get("CONSUMER_KEY")
consumer_secret = os.environ.get("CONSUMER_SECRET")

# Be sure to add replace the text of the with the text you wish to Tweet. You can also add parameters to post polls, quote Tweets, Tweet with reply settings, and Tweet to Super Followers in addition to other features.
payload = {"text": "Hello world!"}

# Get request token
request_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=oob&x_auth_access_type=write"
oauth = OAuth1Session(consumer_key, client_secret=consumer_secret)

try:
    fetch_response = oauth.fetch_request_token(request_token_url)
except ValueError:
    print(
        "There may have been an issue with the consumer_key or consumer_secret you entered."
    )

resource_owner_key = fetch_response.get("oauth_token")
resource_owner_secret = fetch_response.get("oauth_token_secret")
print("Got OAuth token: %s" % resource_owner_key)

# Get authorization
base_authorization_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
authorization_url = oauth.authorization_url(base_authorization_url)
print("Please go here and authorize: %s" % authorization_url)
verifier = input("Paste the PIN here: ")

# Get the access token
access_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
oauth = OAuth1Session(
    consumer_key,
    client_secret=consumer_secret,
    resource_owner_key=resource_owner_key,
    resource_owner_secret=resource_owner_secret,
    verifier=verifier,
)
oauth_tokens = oauth.fetch_access_token(access_token_url)

access_token = oauth_tokens["oauth_token"]
access_token_secret = oauth_tokens["oauth_token_secret"]

# Make the request
oauth = OAuth1Session(
    consumer_key,
    client_secret=consumer_secret,
    resource_owner_key=access_token,
    resource_owner_secret=access_token_secret,
)

# Making the request
response = oauth.post(
    "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets",
    json=payload,
)

if response.status_code != 201:
    raise Exception(
        "Request returned an error: {} {}".format(response.status_code, response.text)
    )

print("Response code: {}".format(response.status_code))

# Saving the response as JSON
json_response = response.json()
print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Source: https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/main/Manage-Tweets/create_tweet.py

I hope this helps.